# \n in textarea gets interpreted when transferring to php server

Tags: php, special-characters

So I enter

`hello \n \n my friend \n !`

into a textarea.
Then I store it into db, I retrieve it, and what I get is

```
hello

my friend
!
```

But I did not want the \n get translated into actual newlines.

So this is my example setup:

```
<textarea name="mytextarea">$mytext</textarea>
```

on the server i do:

store

```
$mydbtextstore = $_POST["mytextarea"];

$modsql = " UPDATE mytable SET text = " . "'" . $mydbtextstore . "'" ;
mysql_query($modsql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

retrieve

```
$descSQL = " SELECT  text
               FROM mytable;"
$descRes = mysql_query($descSQL, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$descRow = mysql_fetch_array($descRes);
$mytext = $descRow["text"];
```

What am I missing?
The textarea MUST reproduce and contain this:

`\n`

Comment: you actully typed in `\n` ?

Comment: [***YOUR CODE IS DANGEROUSLY FLAWED. STOP WHATEVER YOU'RE DOING AND READ THIS.***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Also, stop using PHP's `mysql_` functions. They're deprecated and will soon disappear. Start again using the [MySQL Improved](http://php.net/mysqli) functions.

Comment: @dagon yes thats what I want

Comment: aside the sql injection that is out of question scope , why do you need to print \n

Comment: @KamalSaleh the text gets read by PlantUML to draw an activity diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes with another backslashes. Funny, right?

So after you submitted your text do like this:

```
$text = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $text);
```

so you will have following:

```
hello \\n \\n my friend \\n !
```

and when you insert it in your database it will look like a string with only one backslashes

Comment: do you know, in which cases this happens, and which it does not? E.g. what db setup or whatever to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

You could use a str_replace like this, after the retrieving of the data.

```
$mytext = str_replace("\","&#92;",$mytext);
```

You will replace the slash with its html-entity if you use this code.

EDIT: or use htmlentities on the whole string.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Using `mysql_` functions are unsafe but it does not mean the answer should be downvoted because it still address the issue of replacing line breaks from the textarea.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I can't remember asking for sql injection.

Comment: I tried using `echo str_replace("\\","&#92;","a \n b \n c"); 
echo "a \n b \n c";echo htmlspecialchars("a \n b \n c" , ENT_COMPAT , "ISO-8859-1");echo htmlentities ("a \n b \n c");` on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ . Nothing seems to work

Comment: I figured out the problem is the storing / retrieving of the `\n` . They don't get stored as `\n` but as an actual newline